# How can I make this class immutable despite having a mutable member?

Tags: java, list, immutability

I want to make the following class immutable, even though it has a mutable List member. How can I achieve this?

```
class MyImmutableClass {
        private List<Integer> data;
        public MyImmutableClass(List<Integer> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public List<Integer> getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Below is test class whose `main()` function that modifies object state.

```
class TestMyImmutableClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        data.add(2);
        data.add(5);
        MyImmutableClass obj = new MyImmutableClass(data);
        obj.getData().add(3);
        System.out.println("Data is; " + obj.getData());
    }
}
```

O/P : `Data is; [2, 5, 3]`

Comment: I don't completely understand your test case.  If the class is immutable you should not be able to add the 3.

Comment: Also, add `final` on the member variable.

Comment: You got a great answer from @MadProgrammer, but this may help you in the future: http://mutabilitydetector.org . It will allow you to write a unit test to check if your class is immutable, and guide you on how to fix it. Disclaimer: I wrote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can change the type of `MyImmutableClass.data` to [`ImmutableList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/ImmutableList.html).

```
class MyImmutableClass {
    private ImmutableList<Integer> data;
    public MyImmutableClass(List<Integer> data) {
        this.data = Lists.immutable.withAll(data);
    }
    public ListIterable<Integer> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Eclipse Collection's `ImmutableList` and `ListIterable` types are contractually immutable, meaning they don't have `add()` and `remove()` methods. This way, it's clear from the return type of `getData()` that the returned list cannot be changed.

Both `ImmutableList` and `MutableList` extend `ListIterable` so you could change the implementation from an `ImmutableList` to an unmodifiable list without changing the API.

```
class MyImmutableClass {
    private MutableList<Integer> data;
    public MyImmutableClass(List<Integer> data) {
        this.data = Lists.mutable.withAll(data);
    }
    public ListIterable<Integer> getData() {
        return data.asUnmodifiable();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 7):

In you `getData` method, instead of returning a reference to your `List` like...

```
public List<Integer> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

You could return an unmodifiable `List` instead

```
public List<Integer> getData() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(data);
}
```

See [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) for more details...

**Updated**

As pointed out by user949300, you should also make a copy of the original list.

```
public MyImmutableClass(List<Integer> data) {
    this.data = new ArrayList<Integer>(data);
}
```

This will prevent any one who has access to the original list from making modifications to it.

Comment: -1 Sorry, have to ding this one, as the list can still be modified by the caller who passed you the list.  See my answer.

Comment: @user949300 +1 for your answer, if for nothing else for seeing that initial error...

Comment: I'm typing on my Nook so the detailed explanation will be missing from mine and your's will be the winner.  Plus, your's is now a good answer.

Comment: @user949300 I appreciate the feedback nonetheless! (also you gave me an opportunity to win back that vote ;))

Comment: This is a great use case for Guava `ImmutableList`.

Comment: @chrylis Nice point, add it as comment to the original question!

Comment: @MadProgrammer..so if we consider user949300's answer then we don't need to make any change in getData() method.

Comment: @user2745108 I would, because you are still passing back a "live" collection, that anyone calling `getData` would be able to modify and those changes would be reflected back in the `MyImmutableClass` class...which would mean that the class wasn't immutable...

Comment: I changed `MyImmutableClass` constructor to `this.data = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(data));` and leave getData() same as mentioned in question.  I din't make any change in `TestMyImmutableClass` then i got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. It means `MyImmutableClass ` is immutable now.

Comment: Yes.  The question is, do you want the `List` to remain unmodifiable by the `MyImmutableClass` class.  Sometimes, you want the container class to be able to modify the data, but disallow modifications directly from the outside...

Answer (score 6):

In your constructor, go

`this.data = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(data));`

For completeness and clarity, declare the data field as `final`.